# and statement with dates gives back everything

Tags: android, greendao

I'm having trouble with a query in GreenDAO.

This is the code:

```
QueryBuilder<Thing> qb = this.thingDao.queryBuilder();
qb.and(Properties.StartDate.lt(this.cal.getTime()), Properties.EndDate.ge(this.cal.getTime()));
List<Thing> thingsForToday = qb.list();
```

I expected GreenDAO to return just the things where the StartDate is in the past of cal.getTime() but not the things where the EndDate is passed by cal.getTime(). What I've seen is that GreenDAO just returns every data set (thing) for any given date. No matter if it is before the StartDate or after the EndDate. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use and(), use where().

The "and"/"or" methods are meant to be used a different way. To quote the JavaDoc of "and":

> Creates a WhereCondition by combining the given conditions using AND.
>   The returned WhereCondition must be used inside where(WhereCondition,
>   WhereCondition) or whereOr(WhereCondition, WhereCondition,
>   WhereCondition).

Comment: Okay, this actually is a bit embarrassing. I'll just lay the blame on the late hour. Works like a charm! Thanks! :)

The correct code looks like this:


`QueryBuilder<Thing> qb = this.thingDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where(qb.and(Properties.StartDate.lt(this.cal.getTime()), Properties.EndDate.ge(this.cal.getTime())));
List<Thing> thingsForToday = qb.list();`

Comment: One more tip: You don't need the inner "and", the conditions given to "where" are combined using AND anyway. The "and" and "or" methods are used to build complex conditions involving at least one OR.